# Create a new column based on multiple columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple columns with lists of integers and some null values (eg. None; [1, 27], [13]). For each row, I want to check if any of the columns in the list of columns have the value `1` in their list and, if so, enter `True` into a new column.
For example, the new column `Condition` should look like this.

| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | Condition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| None | [1, 27] | [2] | True |
| None | [-1, 3] | [5] | False |

I tried using `np.where` like this: `df['Condition'] = pd.np.where(1 in df['ID1'], True, False)`. (Not sure how to start with multiple columns, yet). However, it returns `True` for every column in `Condition`. I think it is checking across all the rows in the column to see if any contain `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `issubset`:

```
df["Condition"] = df.filter(like="ID").fillna("").apply(lambda s: s.map({1}.issubset)).any(axis=1)

>>> df

    ID1      ID2  ID3  Condition
0  None  [1, 27]  [2]       True
1  None  [-1, 3]  [5]      False
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
df['condition'] = (df.apply(lambda x: x.explode())
                   .eq(1).any(axis=1).groupby(level=0).agg(any))
```

Output:

```
    ID1      ID2  ID3  condition
0  None  [1, 27]  [2]       True
1  None  [-1, 3]  [5]      False
```

Comment: I'm not sure if either of these are faster or look better, but you can use the parameter `aixs = 1` in your `apply` as well:  `df.apply(lambda x: x.explode(), axis = 1).eq(1).any(axis = 1)` ... or ... `df.apply(lambda x: x.explode() == 1, axis = 1).any(axis = 1)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, @MichaelS.! Your approach is excellent, as avoids the `groupby` and, therefore, should be more efficient than mine. Thanks again for sharing it with me!

Comment: @MichaelS. it's not (see timing in my answer). `explode` should generally be avoided if you only use it as a way to flatten data and not to create a final state of a DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks, @mozway, for letting us know that: I did not know that `explode` should be avoided.

Comment: I meant in terms of efficiency, even if progress was made it's still heavy as it generates a full Series/DataFrame while we only care here about the values

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using pure python:

```
cols = ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3']
df['Condition'] = [any(1 in x for x in row if x)
                   for row in zip(*(df[c] for c in cols))]
```

Output:

```
    ID1      ID2  ID3  Condition
0  None  [1, 27]  [2]       True
1  None  [-1, 3]  [5]      False
```

Comparison of approaches:

*NB. I didn't include @NavkarJain solution as it wasn't running properly.*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of columns from where you need to generate your condition. You can try below simple approach:

```
# Function to check if 1 exists in a list or None
def check_for_num(col, num):
    return True if num is not None and 1 in num else False

# Applying the function to each row for the specified columns and creating 'Condition'
list_columns = ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3']
num = 1

df['Condition'] = df[list_columns].apply(lambda row: any(check_for_num(col, num) for col in row), axis=1)
```